# Why is a $MockitoMock$ instance not being identified as a mock?

Tags: java, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito

I'm using Kotlin, Mockito, and MockitoJRunner to run the following simplified test:

```
open class SomeClassToBeMocked @Inject constructor() {
    fun map(foo: Foo): Bar {...}
}

@Mock
private lateinit var someMock: SomeClassToBeMocked
@InjectMocks
private lateinit var subject: Subject

@Test
fun shouldAssertSomething() {
    val foo = Foo() // from Foo.kt
    val bar = Bar() // from Bar.java from *another module*
    whenever(someMock.map(foo)).thenReturn(bar) // breakpoint[1]

    subject.myMethod(foo)

    verify(someMock).map(foo)
}
```

This pattern works in other parts of the code, but not in this particular test, where I get the following error message:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
   Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.
```

When I debug the code at `breakpoint[1]`, I can see that someMock is an instance of the class `SomeClassToBeMocked$MockitoMock$`. Furthermore, if I try to call `someMock.map(foo)` immediately before `breakpoint[1]`, it does indeed run the original method, instead of returning `null` like all mocks.

Any ideas of what could be happening here?

**UPDATE-1**: I've checked all possibilities for option 1 in the error message. I have also tried `mock(SomeClassToBeMocked::class.java)` and get the same error message. This consistently happens with some of the simplest classes, with a single public method that only converts object A into object B.

**UPDATE-2**: If it makes any difference, I just noticed that in the cases where this happens, `Bar()` lives in a different module than the tests. I've updated the code to reflect this.

**UPDATE-3**: If I create an interface called `SomeClassToBeMocked` and rename the original class to `SomeClassToBeMockedImpl`, everything works like a charm. However, I'd still like to figure out why this happens and how to avoid having to create an interface for this.

Comment: does it work if you explicitly create someMock = mock(SomeClassToBeMocked.class);?

Comment: Did you check all the possibilities listed in clause 1 of the error message?  That is, could the method be final, private, or declared in a non-public parent class?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem yes, all possibilities have been checked. The class looks exactly like the one I posted here: same signature for the class and method.

Comment: @MaciejKowalski it doesn't: I get the exact same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to mock the return value of a function with Mockito you need to mark it with the `open` keyword:

```
open class SomeClassToBeMocked @Inject constructor() {
    open fun map(foo: Foo): Bar {...}
}
```

The problem is that Mockito cannot mock final (which cannot be overriden) functions. Unlike Java, Kotlin requires explicit annotations for overridable members.

Comment: If you look at the code example in my question you can see that the class I'm trying to mock is already open. Any other ideas?

Comment: You must mark both the `SomeClassToBeMocked` class and the `map` function with the `open` modifier. My answer is saying about opening the function, please check it carefully one more time.

Comment: @andersonvom were you able to fix the issue using my answer?